# Imagens enviadas como anexo em e-mail com thymeleaf

Tags: java, email, thymeleaf

Olá, estou fazendo o envio de template de e-mail com dados dinâmicos utilizando o thymeleaf. O e-mail é exibido corretamente com as imagens, porém, as imagens também estão sendo anexadas no corpo do e-mail, o qual não deve ocorrer.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- I need put the image backgroud via css!-->
<body th:style="'background-image: url('+ |cid:${background}| +')'">
    <!--my image-->
    <img src="../../../static/images/email/topo_email.png" th:src="|cid:${logo}|"/>
</body>
```

**Java:**

```
//the main code of the method is here:

String emailFormatado = contatoEmail.getDescricao().replace(System.lineSeparator(), "<br>");
contatoEmail.setDescricao(emailFormatado);

Context context = new Context(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
context.setVariable("contatoEmail", contatoEmail);
context.setVariable("logo", "logo");
context.setVariable("background", "background");

try {
    String corpoEmail = thymeleaf.process("admin/mail/EmailResposta", context);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
    helper.setFrom(contatoEmail.getUsuario().getEmail());
    helper.setTo(email);
    helper.setSubject(String.format("Mensagem de respota"));
    helper.setText(corpoEmail, true);

    helper.addInline("background", new ClassPathResource("static/images/email/background_email.png"));
    helper.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("static/images/email/topo_email.png"));

    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    logger.error("Erro enviando e-mail", e);
```

Fiz algumas variações no código, mas sem sucesso. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

No código java, estava faltando informar o tipo da imagem na variável da mesma:

```
helper.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("static/images/email/topo_email.png"), "image/png");
```

Answer (score 1):

Dois anos depois e ainda me ajudou.

Eu complementei da seguinte forma:

```
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\telefone.png").getCanonicalPath());
helper.addInline("telefoneid", file, "image/png");
```

Caso queira que a imagem vá anexada descomente

```
//helper.addAttachment("telefone.png", file);

mimeMessage.setContent(mail.getContent(), "text/html;charset=utf-8");

mailSender.send(mail);
```